# Inserting a row not working

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Can someone tell me why this code isn't working? I keep getting error at line 1 and 2.

I want to  insert a row into the `PROBLEMTABLE` table for each row in the `CUSTLA` table, where `CustCode` does not match a PK value in the `CUSTCATEGORY` source table.

The error at line 1 does not give me a reason but the error at line 2 says the column is ambiguously defined.

```
INSERT INTO PROBLEMTABLE (problemid, source_rowid, source_table, filterid, datetime, action)
    SELECT 
        PROBLEM_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ROWID, 'CUSTLA', 2, CURRENT_DATE, 'MODIFY'
    FROM 
        CUSTLA U, CUSTCATEGORY Y
    WHERE 
        U.CustCode != Y.CustCode;

SELECT * FROM PROBLEMTABLE;
```

Comment: Can you give us the whole text of the error?

Comment: description has been edited @GiorgosBetsos

Comment: Both tables CUSTLA and CUSTCATEGORY contain a column with the same name, perhaps column ROWID. In your `SELECT` statement, add table alias to the column that exists in both tables, eg `SELECT U.ROWID ...`

Comment: What's your RDBMS?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly checking for not existing records in `CUSTLA`table. Try this query instead:

```
INSERT INTO PROBLEMTABLE (problemid, source_rowid, source_table, 
                          filterid, datetime, action)
    SELECT PROBLEM_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ROWID, 'CUSTLA', 
           2, CURRENT_DATE, 'MODIFY'
    FROM CUSTLA U
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUSTCATEGORY Y WHERE U.CustCode = Y.CustCode)
```

The error you get is due to a field specified in the `SELECT`clause, that exists in *both* `CUSTLA` and `CUSTCATEGORY` tables. This is called an ambiguous field since the RDBMS engine cannot decide which one to choose from.

**Note:** Your query is using an implicit `CROSS JOIN` to check for not existing records. You are going to get a lot of redundant records this way.